# Strapi internationalization with default data via default language

Tags: internationalization, strapi

I have managed to localize my content using strapi's internationalization plugin but I haven't found a solution to be able to use the localized data for all languages the way I need.

The API is used by and app and there's a need for users to have their own localized data.
Lets say we have an content type called Appointments. If a user creates an appointment called `appointmentEnglish` in English he can use a get request and see it, if the user changes languages there's no appointment. How can Strapi use the default language for all the instances of the object until the user fills it with his localized data?

Answer (score 1):

In the Content-Type Builder, in the advanced settings, you can decide whether the field has localization or not.

If you uncheck "Enable localization for this field", its value will became common to all locales.

[image]